# Gradle - plugin maven-publish: How to publish only specific publication to a repository

Tags: gradle, maven-plugin

We have two different artifacts that is going to be published to two different maven repositories.

- "**ProjectXMergedWar**" should be published to "**MyMavenRepo1**" (snapshots)
- "**ProjectXJarRelease**" should be published to "**MyMavenRepo2**" (release)
- "ProjectXMergedWar" should never be published to "MyMavenRepo2" (release)
- "ProjectXJarRelease" should never be published to "MyMavenRepo1" (snapshots)

We use the plugin [maven-publish](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) where you configure a set of publications and reposistories. The plugin then generates tasks for all combinations of publications and repositories (see tasks list at the bottom). Currently the tasks `publish` and `publishRelease` is doing what we want, but there are tasks we don't want.

Some solutions might be:

- Can we **remove the unwanted tasks**?**
- Can we configure maven-publish to **only generate two publish tasks** (the wanted tasks*)?
- Can we call the **correct classes directly** (`repo.publish(artifact)` or something like that)?

I have looked at the source code of `PublishToMavenRepository`. It seems like the action I want to achive is located in `protected void doPublish`.

***Wanted tasks:**

- publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository + generatePom
- publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository + generatePom

****Unwanted tasks:**

- publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository
- publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
publishing {
    publications {
        ProjectXMergedWar(MavenPublication) {
            artifact mergeWar
            artifactId = 'projectx'
        }
        ProjectXJarRelease(MavenPublication) {
            artifact releaseJar
            artifactId = 'projectx'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'MyMavenRepo1'
            url 'http://artifactory/url/our-snapshot-local'
            credentials { (...) }
        }
        maven {
            name 'MyMavenRepo2'
            url 'http://artifactory/url/our-release-local'
            credentials { (...) }
        }
    }
}

task publish(dependsOn: [
    'generatePomFileForProjectXMergedWarPublication',
    'publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository'
], overwrite: true) {
    // We override the normal publish which would have tried to publish all combinations of defined
    // publications and repositories:
    // - publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository      (we use this in normal snapshot publish)
    // - publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository      (not to be used)
    // - publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository     (not to be used)
    // - publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository     (we use this one in publishRelease)
}
task publishRelease(dependsOn: [
    'generatePomFileForProjectXJarReleasePublication',
    'publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository'
])
```

Output from tasks:

```
$ ./gradlew tasks

(...)

Publishing tasks
----------------
generatePomFileForProjectXJarReleasePublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'ProjectXJarRelease'.
generatePomFileForProjectXMergedWarPublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'ProjectXMergedWar'.
publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXJarRelease' to the local Maven repository.
publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXJarRelease' to Maven repository 'MyMavenRepo1'.
publishProjectXJarReleasePublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXJarRelease' to Maven repository 'MyMavenRepo2'.
publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXMergedWar' to the local Maven repository.
publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo1Repository - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXMergedWar' to Maven repository 'MyMavenRepo1'.
publishProjectXMergedWarPublicationToMyMavenRepo2Repository - Publishes Maven publication 'ProjectXMergedWar' to Maven repository 'MyMavenRepo2'.
publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the local Maven cache.

(...)

Other tasks
-----------
(...)
publish
publishRelease
(...)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could disable and hide the "invalid" tasks like so:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name 'Dev'
            url 'http://dev/'
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
        }

        maven {
            name 'Prod'
            url 'http://prod/'
            credentials {
                username 'username'
                password 'password'
            }
        }

    }

    publications {
        // This will only be enabled on Dev
        MyDevJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId "test"
            version "1.0"
            groupId "org.example"
            artifact file('abc')
            ext.repo = 'Dev'
        }

        // This will only be enabled on prod
        MyJar(MavenPublication) {
            artifactId "test"
            version "1.0"
            groupId "org.example"
            artifact file('abc')
            ext.repo = 'Prod'
        }
    }
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) { task ->
        if (task.publication.hasProperty('repo') && task.publication.repo != task.repository.name) {
            task.enabled = false
            task.group = null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Knut, your answer seem good but for some reason it wasn't working for me anymore, i've added a new post with my solution if you can take a look at.

Answer (score 5):

Probably this didn't exist when the question was asked, but the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_customization.html#sec:publishing_maven:conditional_publishing) describes just how to achieve the desired *conditional* publishing.

Using method `tasks.withType()` as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23350736/3066295), but then using an `onlyIf{}` block as well.

> "Gradle allows you to skip any task you want based on a condition via the `Task.onlyIf(org.gradle.api.specs.Spec)` method."

So their example uses conditions on the *repository name* and *publication type*:

```
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) {
    onlyIf {
        (repository == publishing.repositories.external &&
            publication == publishing.publications.binary) ||
        (repository == publishing.repositories.internal &&
            publication == publishing.publications.binaryAndSources)
    }
}
tasks.withType(PublishToMavenLocal) {
    onlyIf {
        publication == publishing.publications.binaryAndSources
    }
}
```

Where they have defined `publications` and `repositories` as follows:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        binary(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
        binaryAndSources(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourcesJar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        // change URLs to point to your repos, e.g. http://my.org/repo
        maven {
            name = 'external'
            url = "$buildDir/repos/external"
        }
        maven {
            name = 'internal'
            url = "$buildDir/repos/internal"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just started playing with gradle and it's other plugins and @knut-saua-mathiesen solution was really interresting, however it wasn't working for me.

Inside the 'AfterEvaluate' the task.publication wasn't set to it's correcte value but initialized to 'null'. So i tried a few other things and came up with this solution :

```
afterEvaluate {                                                                                   
  tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository).all { publishTask ->                                   
    publishTask.onlyIf { task ->                                                                  
      if (task.publication.hasProperty('repo') && task.publication.repo != task.repository.name) {
        task.enabled = false                                                                      
        task.group = null                                                                         
        return false                                                                              
      }                                                                                           
      return true                                                                                 
    }                                                                                             
  }                                                                                               
}
```