# Gradle publish repository defaults or ignores

Tags: gradle, publish, gradlew

I have defined multiple repositories to publish to, but want the "gradle publish" job only to deploy to some of them.

E.g. in the following configuration I want that a "gradle publish" deploys the artifact to repo_a and repo_b but NOT repo_c.
A deploy to repo_c should only be done when the publishMavenJavaPublicationToRepo_cRepositoryjob is activated.

Is that somehow possible?

Thanks

```
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://repo_a/maven-releases/"
            credentials {
                username 'xxx'
                password 'xxx'
            }
            name "repo_a"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repo_b/maven-releases/"
            credentials {
                username 'xxx'
                password 'xxx'
            }
            name "repo_b"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repo_c/maven-releases/"
            credentials {
                username 'xxx'
                password 'xxx'
            }
            name "repo_c"
        }

    }
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code snippet to disable your `publishMavenJavaPublicationToRepo_cRepository` publishing task ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21433251/gradle-plugin-maven-publish-how-to-publish-only-specific-publication-to-a-rep)):

```
afterEvaluate {
  tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository) { task ->
    if (task.repository.name == "repo_c") {
        task.enabled = false
        task.group = null
    }
  }
}
```