# Gradle: Condition base publishing package on maven repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build.gradle

I have a gradle file for building a JAR and publishing it in a maven repository on nexus server.

### `build.gradle` file

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            artifact shadowJar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username nexusUsername
                password nexusPassword
            }
            if (IsSnapshot.toBoolean())
                url "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-snapshots/"
            else
                url "${nexusUrl}/repository/maven-releases/"
        }
    }
}
```

This task publishes a JAR file to the respective repository(snapshot/releases) based on the value of `IsSnapshot`.

I have one more variable: `DoPublish`. If `DoPublish` is `true`, then I want to publish the package; otherwise, I don't want to publish the package on nexus.

I am thinking I should set `url` to an empty string in such cases. Are there any better suggestions?

### Output of gradle task

> Publishing tasks
>
> generatePomFileFor{module1}Publication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'module1'.
>
> generatePomFileFor{module2}Publication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'module2'.
>
> generatePomFileForMavenPublication - Generates the Maven POM file for publication 'maven'.
>
> publish - Publishes all publications produced by this project.
>
> publish{module1}PublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'module1' to the local Maven repository.
>
> publish{module1}PublicationToMavenRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'module1' to Maven repository 'maven'.
>
> publish{module2}PublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'module2' to the local Maven repository.
>
> publish{module2}PublicationToMavenRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'module2' to Maven repository 'maven'.
>
> publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal - Publishes Maven publication 'maven' to the local Maven repository.
>
> publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository - Publishes Maven publication 'maven' to Maven repository 'maven'.
>
> publishToMavenLocal - Publishes all Maven publications produced by this project to the local Maven cache.

Comment: seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21433251/7224691. May be useful for other viewers (as it was for me) with more publications/projects setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tasks can be conditionally deactivated using `onlyIf` as described in the gradle documentation: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:using_a_predicate

The task in question here is `publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository`, as described here https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html, and this is the one that needs to be disabled:

```
publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository.onlyIf { IsSnapshot.toBoolean() }
```

Because the task `publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository` is dynamically generated upon a successful publishing configuration it may not be available when the build script is parsed and evaluated resulting in an exception. In this case, one can update it upon completing the task gragh:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph -> 
  publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository.onlyIf { IsSnapshot.toBoolean() }
}
```

It may be a different task if you use a different publishing plugin, but the idea is the same

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will check this within few days and will mark it as answer.

Comment: I am getting exception while i add "publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository.onlyIf { false }"  Exception thrown while executing model rule: PublishingPlugin.Rules#publishing(ExtensionContainer) Could not get unknown property 'publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.internal.DefaultPublishingExtension.

Comment: I tried to consult the docs for the name of the task that the `publish` plugin defines. Apparently it is something different. Run `./gradlew tasks` to find out which tasks are defined by `publish` and apply the same technique there. Exactly as the last sentence says: it may be a different task, but the idea is the same. The docs are saying: `The created task is named “publish«PUBNAME»PublicationTo«REPONAME»Repository”`

Comment: I tried gradle task command and "publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository" is valid task name. I have added publication task list in question

Comment: Tricky. The task is probably dynamically generated either when the plugin is applied or when the plugin specification is complete. You could try using the above logic in a callback of configuration evaluation: `gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { graph -> publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository.onlyIf { IsSnapshot.toBoolean() } }` IMO the particular plugin in question is quite bad, but it does not help your case obviously

Comment: Thanks for accepting. Did this work with the `whenReady` callback? Should I update the answer for the benefit of others, or suggest an edit yourself?

Comment: I tried your suggested option, with taskGraph.whenReady. It worked for me, Thanks you.